# how to read property from jenkins while i want the key to be a variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, properties, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

i read a prop file from local like:
def props = readProperties  file: 'dir/my.properties'
and in jenkins file, i want access the key/value from this file,so i do:

```
 def myCustomKey = "test_"+ENV
```

when i try to get value from props by my custom key, i don't know how to get it, i have try below:

```
    echo "props: ${props[$myCustomKey]}"
    echo "props: ${props."$myCustomKey"}"
    echo "props: ${props.myCustomKey}"
```

it is not working at all.anyone know how to get the value of my props with the key is a variable?

Comment: `echo "props: ${props[myCustomKey]}"`

Comment: What is the final value of myCustomKey? Is it the value you expect it to be? Did you try to echo it?

Comment: groovy seems not work with this, i try this and it is working:
def strofkey=myCustomKey.toString()
def myval = props[strofkey]

Answer (score 0):

```
def myCustomKey = "test_"+ENV

echo """props: ${props."$myCustomKey"}"""
```

Comment: thank you for answer this, i fix it by doing def strofkey=myCustomKey.toString() def myval = props[strofkey]